# Java: how do I check if a node (javax.jcr.node) property exists?

Tags: aem, jcr

I just want to find out if a node property exists.

I was looking at the API reference guide

- Node (Content Repository for Java Technology API Version 2.0) (click [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html))
- Property (Content Repository for Java Technology API Version 2.0) (click [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Property.html))

and nothing there stands out.

Thanks

Comment: You should use the Sling API if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasProperty()` From the same link that you've posted - [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html#hasProperty(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

you can check by

boolean has_prop = rootNode.hasProperty("jcr:created");